# When the openssl locking callback is called

Tags: callback, openssl, cryptography, thread-safety, crash-dumps

In my server application, I am using openssl with multi threads. I set a locking callback function to use openssl thread saftly.  But the callback function might not be called. Any logs in the callback func were not printed.

I expected that the logs were printed when the ssl_read or ssl_write was called.

How can I check the callback function is set correctly and called normally?

I refered the openssl/mttest.c to set the locking callback function to my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL are you using? Locking callbacks are not required, and not used, in OpenSSL 1.1.0+

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If the version is 1.1.0+ then any settings are not required for using multi threads? Otherwise when the callback should be called? My expect is right?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special in 1.1.0+ to set up OpenSSL for multi threads. It will automatically lock as appropriate for the underlying threading library as long as you don't (except where noted otherwise in the docs) share an individual object (such as an SSL object) across multiple threads: https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG1